# Sequelize findAll method not returning entries in the database

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have connected my app to an existing database. The database table currently has 3 entries but, when I query the model using findAll only an empty array is returned. Im not sure if this has something to do with the database already and existing and connecting to it through models. I am also syncing all files in the index file in the models directory.

```js
//Courses Model for sequelize

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    class Courses extends Sequelize.Model{}

    Courses.init({
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },

        title: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },

        description: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT,
            allowNull: false
        },

        estimatedTime: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },

        materialsNeeded: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },

        createdAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        },

        updatedAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        },

        userId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {sequelize, modelName: 'courses'});
    
    Courses.associate = (models) => {
        models.courses.belongsTo(models.users, {foreignKey: "userId"});
    };

    return Courses
}
```

```js
// Router with findAll query

const router = require('express').Router();
const db = require('../models/');



router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(await db.courses.findAll());   
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    
    res.json({msg: "None"})
});

module.exports = router;
```

[This is the courses table currently][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KkK6.png

Answer (score 0):

This is javascript level issuse I guess. You can't use await statement like that. Please try this out first.

```js
onst router = require('express').Router();
const db = require('../models/');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const courese = await db.courses.findAll()

        console.log(courses)
        res.send({ courses })
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    
    res.json({msg: "None"})
});

module.exports = router;
```

If the problem remains after running this, check if your config is pointing right database.

For checking whether this is problem.

1. Change your config to point existing database
2. Run the code
3. Change your config to point local database with different schema
4. Do the sequelize sync
5. Run the code

By doing so, you can check what is the real problem in your code.